# Syncing directory between Kubuntu and Windows 7

Tags: linux, windows, rsync, kubuntu

I recently came across an issue on my work computer. I'm running Kubuntu 14.04 as my main development OS and Windows 7 for compatibility with some company software and network stuff. My problem is that, since the linux OS is the main one, I want to store my data in my home on an ext4 partition. But I need my data in Windows as well, since I have to do some work in there.

My idea of a solution is run a script at system startup that will use rsync to synchronize given directories between windows and kubuntu partitions. (its mostly documents and source codes, so the size doubling isn't a problem). That way I would have an updated data all the time and on top of that, kind of a backup in case of corrupted partition.

I can easily do that in linux - in fact it would be a really short script written in minutes. But the problem here is: is there any way to do this in Windows? I mean - can I access ext4 partition from cmd in windows? I know that there are GUI tools that can access ext4 partitions, but I can't use them in a script.

Has anyone faced similar issue, or know of a cmd tool that can help me achieve that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Ext2Fsd: http://www.ext2fsd.com/

> Ext2Fsd is a Windows file system driver for the Ext2, Ext3, and Ext4
>   file systems. It allows Windows to read Linux file systems natively,
>   providing access to the file system via a drive letter that any
>   program can access.

Comment: That seems like exactly what I need - I can't believe that I haven't come across that tool. Thanks, I will try it and come back here to accept!

Answer (score 0):

Kubuntu has NTFS read/write using ntfs-3g... Why don't you create an NTFS partition away from both Windows and Kubuntu so that both OSes can read/write to it. You could then use scripts on either side to use and backup your data. Backup to another disk, however. You could then use fstab to automount the partition in Kubuntu to a directory of your choosing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This is how I actually have it now, but Kubuntu is my primary, so I want data stored on a native linux partition. The NTFS support in *buntu is on a high level, but there are still some drawbacks compared to native filesystem.